# error: ‘int pow(double, int)’ conflicts with a previous declaration int pow(double a, int n) {

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

My linux version is 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u1 (2019-09-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
My gcc version is 8.3.0
i want to compile and run Sniper 7.2 with Pin 3.5.
i am trying to compile benchmarks according to this post:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/snipersim/2yL2x6nNfVs/EmqQlVf6EwAJ

but i get this error:

```
/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:121:24: error: ‘int pow(double, int)’ conflicts with a previous declaration int pow(double a, int n) {
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/math.h:36,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common/RTInclude.hxx:18,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common/RTVec.hxx:4,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common/RTBox.hxx:4,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:3:
/usr/include/c++/8/cmath:399:3: note: previous declaration ‘double std::pow(double, int)’   pow(double __x, int __i)
                                                                                                                                                   ^~~

/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:143:39: error: call of overloaded ‘pow(double, int)’ is ambiguous
     if (v.minIndex() != 1 || dv != pow(convert<DataType>(11), N)) {
                                    ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:424,
                 from /usr/include/time.h:25,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:140:1: note: candidate: ‘double pow(double, double)’
 __MATHCALL_VEC (pow,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ __y));
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried the recommendations from stackflow and others even the note in the report file but nothing changes.
I find out pow() function should be like int pow(int a, int n) or double pow(double a, double n) but in TestRVec.cxx the deceleration is completely wrong.
TestRTVec.cc seems to be built by makefile and then get compiled afterwards because it is not in the sniper_benchmark.tar file so i cannot do anything with that. 
is my observation true and what should i do??

i post a few prior lines in make report below:

```
cd /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL && /usr/bin/g++  -std=gnu++98  -DTHIS_IS_CMAKE -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/libs/mesa/inst/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/include -O3 -funroll-loops -fprefetch-loop-arrays -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -static-libgcc -Wl,--hash-style=both,--as-needed -DPARSEC_VERSION=2.1 -DENABLE_PARSEC_HOOKS -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/libs/hooks/inst/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/include -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/tools/hooks -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/include -fexceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-align-labels -DNDEBUG -D_MM_NO_ALIGN_CHECK  -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/libs/mesa/inst/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/include -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/BVH -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/SG -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/LRT/include -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/LRT   -D__ahmad__ -o CMakeFiles/test_rtvec.dir/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.o -c /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx
```

The whole error section is this:

```
    cd /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL && /usr/bin/g++  -std=gnu++98  -DTHIS_IS_CMAKE -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/libs/mesa/inst/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/include -O3 -funroll-loops -fprefetch-loop-arrays -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -static-libgcc -Wl,--hash-style=both,--as-needed -DPARSEC_VERSION=2.1 -DENABLE_PARSEC_HOOKS -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/libs/hooks/inst/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/include -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/tools/hooks -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/include -fexceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-align-labels -DNDEBUG -D_MM_NO_ALIGN_CHECK  -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/libs/mesa/inst/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/include -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/BVH -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/SG -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/LRT/include -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/LRT   -D__ahmad__ -o CMakeFiles/test_rtvec.dir/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.o -c /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx
/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:121:24: error: ‘int pow(double, int)’ conflicts with a previous declaration
 int pow(double a, int n) {
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/math.h:36,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common/RTInclude.hxx:18,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common/RTVec.hxx:4,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common/RTBox.hxx:4,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:3:
/usr/include/c++/8/cmath:399:3: note: previous declaration ‘double std::pow(double, int)’
   pow(double __x, int __i)
   ^~~
/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx: In instantiation of ‘void testbox() [with int N = 8; DataType = double]’:
/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:317:24:   required from here
/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:143:39: error: call of overloaded ‘pow(double, int)’ is ambiguous
     if (v.minIndex() != 1 || dv != pow(convert<DataType>(11), N)) {
                                    ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:424,
                 from /usr/include/time.h:25,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:140:1: note: candidate: ‘double pow(double, double)’
 __MATHCALL_VEC (pow,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ __y));
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:114:5: note: candidate: ‘int pow(int, int)’
 int pow(int a, int n) {
     ^~~
/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:121:5: note: candidate: ‘int pow(double, int)’
 int pow(double a, int n) {
     ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/math.h:36,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common/RTInclude.hxx:18,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common/RTVec.hxx:4,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/common/RTBox.hxx:4,
                 from /home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/RTTL/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.cxx:3:
/usr/include/c++/8/cmath:415:5: note: candidate: ‘typename __gnu_cxx::__promote_2<_Tp, _Up>::__type std::pow(_Tp, _Up) [with _Tp = double; _Up = int; typename __gnu_cxx::__promote_2<_Tp, _Up>::__type = double]’
     pow(_Tp __x, _Up __y)
     ^~~
/usr/include/c++/8/cmath:407:3: note: candidate: ‘long double std::pow(long double, int)’
   pow(long double __x, int __n)
   ^~~
/usr/include/c++/8/cmath:403:3: note: candidate: ‘float std::pow(float, int)’
   pow(float __x, int __n)
   ^~~
/usr/include/c++/8/cmath:399:3: note: candidate: ‘double std::pow(double, int)’
   pow(double __x, int __i)
   ^~~
/usr/include/c++/8/cmath:392:3: note: candidate: ‘long double std::pow(long double, long double)’
   pow(long double __x, long double __y)
   ^~~
/usr/include/c++/8/cmath:388:3: note: candidate: ‘float std::pow(float, float)’
   pow(float __x, float __y)
   ^~~
make[4]: *** [RTTL/CMakeFiles/test_rtvec.dir/build.make:56: RTTL/CMakeFiles/test_rtvec.dir/test/TestRTVec/TestRTVec.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper'
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:224: RTTL/CMakeFiles/test_rtvec.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:114: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/apps/raytrace/obj/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper'
[PARSEC] Error: 'env CXXFLAGS=-I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/libs/mesa/inst/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/include -O3 -funroll-loops -fprefetch-loop-arrays -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -static-libgcc -Wl,--hash-style=both,--as-needed -DPARSEC_VERSION=2.1 -DENABLE_PARSEC_HOOKS -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/libs/hooks/inst/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/include -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/tools/hooks -I/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/include -fexceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-align-labels -DNDEBUG -D_MM_NO_ALIGN_CHECK LDFLAGS=-L/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/libs/mesa/inst/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec/parsec-2.1/pkgs/libs/hooks/inst/amd64-linux.gcc-sniper/lib -uparmacs_roi_end -uparmacs_roi_start -L/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/tools/hooks -lhooks_base -lrt -pthread LIBS= -lhooks -lXmu -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lpthread /usr/bin/make' failed.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:31: parsec-build] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ahmad/sniper-latest/sniper-7.2/benchmarks/parsec'
make: *** [Makefile:14: all] Error 2
```

The whole code file is this:

```
    #include <time.h>

#include "RTTL/common/RTBox.hxx"
#include "RTTL/common/Timer.hxx"
using namespace RTTL;

template<int N, typename DataType>
void randomize(RTVec_t<N, DataType>& v, float scale = 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.nElements(); i++)
        v[i] = DataType(scale * rand()/float(RAND_MAX));
}

template<int N>
void randomize(RTVec_t<N, sse_f>& v, float scale = 1) {
    float* f = (float*)&v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4*v.nElements(); i++)
        f[i] = float(scale * rand()/float(RAND_MAX));
}

template<int N>
void randomize(RTVec_t<N, sse_i>& v, float scale = 1) {
    int* f = (int*)&v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4*v.nElements(); i++)
        f[i] = int(scale * rand()/float(RAND_MAX));
}

// Elementary types
template<int N, typename DataType>
void test() {
    typedef RTVec_t<N, DataType> rtvec;
    DataType eps = epsilon<DataType>();

    rtvec a(1);
    rtvec b(2);
    rtvec c(3);
    rtvec d(4);

    DataType q = 14;
    rtvec dif = q*a - b - c*d; // should be ~0
    if (dif.absMaximum() != 0) {
        cout << "err101 = " << dif << ";" << endl;
        //exit(101);
    }

    c += 1; // operator+=(const DataType q)
    if (d != c) {
        cout << "err102 = " << c << ";" << endl;
        //exit(102);
    }

    const float scale = 100;
    randomize(a, scale);
    randomize(b, scale);
    randomize(c, scale);

    d = (a+b)*c - (a*c + b*c);
    if (d.absMaximum() > 30 * N * scale * eps) {
        // Could happen (rather infrequently but still)
        cout << "err103 = " << d << ";" << endl;
        //exit(103);
    }

    DataType e[] = {8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    a = 2;
    a *= 2;
    a -= e;
rtvec tt(e);
    a += rtvec(5);
    if (a.maximum() != ((rtvec&)e).maximum() || a.minimum() != ((rtvec&)e).minimum()) {
        cout << "err104 = " << a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(104);
    }

}

// SSE types (also works for int/floats!)
template<int N, typename DataType>
void test4() {
    typedef RTVec_t<N, DataType> rtvec;
    DataType eps = epsilon<DataType>();

    rtvec a(convert<DataType>(1));
    rtvec b(convert<DataType>(2));
    rtvec c(convert<DataType>(3));
    rtvec d(convert<DataType>(4));

    DataType q = convert<DataType>(14);
    rtvec dif = q*a - b - c*d; // should be ~0
    if (dif.absMaximum() != convert<DataType>(0)) {
        cout << "err201 = " << dif << ";" << endl;
        //exit(201);
    }

    c += convert<DataType>(1); // operator+=(const DataType q)
    if (d != c) {
        cout << "err202 = " << c << ";" << endl;
        //exit(202);
    }

    #define scale 100
    randomize(a, scale);
    randomize(b, scale);
    randomize(c, scale);

    d = (a+b)*c - (a*c + b*c);
    DataType dam = d.absMaximum();
    if (!(30 * N * scale * eps >= dam)) {
        cout << "err203 = " << d << ";" << endl;
        //exit(203);
    }

}

int pow(int a, int n) {
    // versions for float/double are defined in stdlib.
    int r = a;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) r *= a;
    return r;
}
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
int pow(double a, int n) {
    return pow(a, (double)n);
}
#endif

template<int N, typename DataType>
void testbox() {
    typedef RTVec_t<N, DataType> rtvec;
    typedef RTBox_t<N, DataType> rtbox;
    rtbox a;
    a[0] = rtvec(2);
    a[1] = rtvec(12);
    rtbox b(rtvec(1), rtvec(10));
    rtbox d = a + b;
    rtbox e = a - b;
    if (d.sides().minimum() != 11 || e.center().maximum() != 6) {
        cout << "err301 = " << a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(301);
    }
    DataType dv = d.volume();
    d[1][0] = 20;
    rtvec v = d.sides();
    if (v.minIndex() != 1 || dv != pow(convert<DataType>(11), N)) {
        cout << "err302 = " << d << ";" << endl;
        //exit(302);
    }
}

template<int N, typename DataType>
void testbox4() {
    typedef RTVec_t<N, DataType> rtvec;
    typedef RTBox_t<N, DataType> rtbox;
    rtbox a;
    a[0] = rtvec(convert<DataType>(2));
    a[1] = rtvec(convert<DataType>(12));
    rtbox b(rtvec(convert<DataType>(1)), rtvec(convert<DataType>(10)));
    rtbox d = a + b;
    rtbox e = a - b;
    if (d.sides().minimum() != 11 || e.center().maximum() != 6) {
        cout << "err303 = " << a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(303);
    }
}

#include "RTTL/common/RTcoutRedirect.hxx"

int main() { 
    Timer timer; timer.start();
    unsigned int seed = (unsigned int)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC*unsigned(time(NULL)));
    srand(seed);

    cout << "seed = " << seed << ";" << endl;

    // Check if alignment is working...
    int align0 = __alignof(RTData_t<3, float,  0>::AlignedDataType) ;
    int alignx = __alignof(RTData_t<3, float, 16>::AlignedDataType);
    if (align0 != __alignof(float) || alignx != __alignof(sse_f)) {
        cout << "err00 = " << align0 << " vs " << alignx << endl;
        //exit(1);
    }

    RTVec_t<4, float, 16> a(0.0f);
    int aa = __alignof(a);
    a.entry(1) = 1;            // default cast (to float&)
    a.entry<float>(2) = 2;     // explicit cast
    a.entry<float>(3) = 3;

    // Different overloads for 'const' attribute (same behavior)
    //const
    _ALIGN(16) float a0[] = {0,1,2,3};
    if (a != (RTVec_t<4, float, 16>&)a0) { // using cast
        cout << "err01 = " << a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(1);
    }
    if (a != a0) {
        cout << "err021 = " << a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(21);
    }
    if (a == *a0) { // operator==
        cout << "err022 = " << a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(22);
    }

    RTVec_t<4, float, 16> b;
    b = 3.0f;
    if (b != a0[3]) { // operator!=
        cout << "err023 = " << a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(23);
    }

    // Mixed operands and casts.
    float* bv = b.pointer<float>();
    bv[0] = 1;
    bv[1] = 2;
    bv[2] = 3;
    bv[3] = 4;
    if (a == b) { // comparing RTVec_t<4, float, 16>
        cout << "err03 = " << a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(3);
    }
    if (a != b - 1) {
        cout << "err04 = " << a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(4);
    }
    if (a != b - 1.0f) {
        cout << "err05 = " << a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(5);
    }

    RTVec_t<1, sse_f> asse;
    asse = convert(3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // _mm_set_ps
    if (asse != a.entry<sse_f>()) {
        cout << "err06 = " << asse << ";" << endl;
        //exit(6);
    }

    // Access individual floats in sse_f vector.
    asse.entry<float>(1) = 5;
    if (asse != convert(3.0f, 2.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f)) {
        cout << "err07 = " << asse << ";" << endl;
        //exit(7);
    }

    // Difference between cast and convert.
    RTVec_t<1, sse_i> assei;
    assei = convert(3, 2, 5, 0);
    if (assei[0] != convert(asse[0])) {
        cout << "err081 = " << assei << ";" << endl;
        //exit(81);
    }
    if (assei[0] == cast(asse[0])) {
        cout << "err082 = " << assei << ";" << endl;
        //exit(82);
    }

    // Check different sizes and data types.

    test<5, float>();
//#if 0
    test<6, float>();
    test<8, float>();
    test<5, int>();
    test<6, int>();
    test<8, int>();
    test<5, double>();
    test<6, double>();
    test<8, double>();

    test4<16, int>();
    test4<16, float>();
    test4<16, sse_f>();

    // Specialized instances.
    test<2, int>();
    test<3, float>();
    test<4, char>();

    test4<3, sse_f>();

    #if !defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
    _ALIGN(16) float ef[] = {4,3,2,1, 8,7,6,5, 11,10,9,8};
    sse_f* e = (sse_f*)ef;
    RTVec_t<3, sse_f> a4;
    a4 = RTVec_t<3, sse_f>(convert(2.0f)); // fine without template parameter
    a4 *= convert<sse_f>(4);               // need one
    a4 -= e;
    sse_f ama = a4.maximum();
    sse_f ami = a4.minimum();
    sse_f adi = ama - ami;
    if (adi != 7) {
        cout << "err09 = " << a4 << ";" << endl;
        //exit(9);
    }
    #endif

    RTVec_t<4, float, 16> at0(1.0f);
    RTVec_t<3, float> at1(1.0f);
    RTVec_t<4, float, 16> at2(1.0f);
    // Vectors of different size are always not equal.
    if (at1 == at0) {
        cout << "err10 = " << at0 << ";" << endl;
        //exit(10);
    }
    // The same size.
    if (at2 != at0) {
        cout << "err11 = " << at0 << ";" << endl;
        //exit(11);
    }

    test4<4, float>();
    test4<4, sse_f>();
    test4<4, sse_i>();

    testbox<2, float>();
    testbox<3, int>();
    testbox<4, float>();
    testbox<8, double>();

    testbox4<1, sse_f>();

    RTBox_t<3, float, 16> b3;
    _ALIGN(16) float b31[] = {1,2,3};
    b3.m_min = (RTVec_t<3, float, 16>&)b31;
    _ALIGN(16) float b32[] = {3,6,5};
    b3.m_max = (RTVec_t<3, float, 16>&)b32;
    int b3i = b3.maxIndex();
    float b3ar = b3.area();
    float b3vol = b3.volume();
    if (b3i != 1 || b3ar != 40 || b3vol != 16) {
        cout << "err12 = " << b3 << ";" << endl;
        //exit(12);
    }

    RTBox_t<1, sse_f> b4;
    b4[0] = _mm_set_ps(1,2,3,4);
    b4[1] = _mm_set_ps(5,5,6,6);
    b4[0].entry<float>(3) = 2;
    sse_f bs = b4.sides()[0];
    RTBox_t<4, float>& bf = (RTBox_t<4, float>&)b4;
    float bfv = bf.volume();
    if (bfv != 54) {
        cout << "err13 = " << b4 << ";" << endl;
        //exit(13);
    }

#if 0
    RTBox3a b3a;
    b3a[0] = _mm_set_ps(-1,3,2,1);
    b3a[1] = _mm_set_ps(-1,5,4,3);
    float b3av = b3a.volume();
    float b3aa = b3a.area();
    if (b3av != 8 || b3aa != 24) {
        cout << "err14 = " << b3a << ";" << endl;
        //exit(14);
    }
#else
    cout << "WARNING: as layout if RTBox3a is unclear, code has been disabled" << endl;
#endif

//#endif
    cout << "success (" << timer.stop() << " seconds)" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error lines are these

```
int pow(int a, int n) {
    // versions for float/double are defined in stdlib.
    int r = a;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) r *= a;
    return r;
}
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
int pow(double a, int n) {
    return pow(a, (double)n);
}
#endif
```

and

```
template<int N, typename DataType>
    void testbox() {
        typedef RTVec_t<N, DataType> rtvec;
        typedef RTBox_t<N, DataType> rtbox;
        rtbox a;
        a[0] = rtvec(2);
        a[1] = rtvec(12);
        rtbox b(rtvec(1), rtvec(10));
        rtbox d = a + b;
        rtbox e = a - b;
        if (d.sides().minimum() != 11 || e.center().maximum() != 6) {
            cout << "err301 = " << a << ";" << endl;
            //exit(301);
        }
        DataType dv = d.volume();
        d[1][0] = 20;
        rtvec v = d.sides();
        if (v.minIndex() != 1 || dv != pow(convert<DataType>(11), N)) {
            cout << "err302 = " << d << ";" << endl;
            //exit(302);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Need to see the code, [mcve] please, but you probably used `using namespace std` where you shouldn't have.

Comment: Thanks to @user4581301 for editing so well my post. i wanted to edit that after a minute. 
I have no code available because it is not my code. i mean it is generated by a make procedure during compiling a software for the first time in linux. the software is Sniper from https://snipersim.org

Comment: @uneven_mark would you please reread the issue? i have completed the report now. Thank you.

Comment: @user4581301 would you please reread the issue? i have completed the report now. Thank you.

Comment: That's a surprise. They defined their own `pow` functions. Turns out I'm right though, `using namespace std;` got you. `std::pow` is being used as a candidate for `pow` and is conflicting with the custom `pow`. It's not shown, but somewhere in the code is a `using namespace std;` Find it. Kill it. Recompile.

Comment: @user4581301 `#include<cmath>` and `#include<math.h>` may also import and/or define `pow` into the global namespace, as long as `#include<cmath>` imports `pow` into `std`. So `using namespace std;` is not required for this to become a problem.

Comment: Double yuck, @uneven_mark . From the G++ headers it looks like you're right. That said, I can't reproduce this failure in C++17 with or without `using namespace std;`

Comment: @user4581301 I also tested and in C++11 and up the error doesn't show up, because (I suspect) the relevant overloads are implemented as template in libstdc++. (Was not allowed before C++11 I think.) This would not cause a redefinition error.

Comment: @user4581301 at some levels of compilation i got errors and i added -std=gnu++98 to makefile in order to overcome the errors. is that causing this issue?

Comment: Don't ask me, Ahmad. @uneven_mark has a better grip on this one. Uneven, makes sense. Template should lose to explicit definition if I'm remembering correctly and please slap me if I'm not.

Comment: @ahmadsedigh The root cause is that the code has a bug (that might have been a fix for a compiler-specific behavior/bug or something similar when it was written). Either ask the author of the code to fix this bug or try one of the workarounds I mentioned in my answer: 1. compile with `-std=gnu++11` or 2. compile with an older GCC version (pre 6.x). Neither of these is guaranteed to work. You might also want to try simply removing the problematic definition from the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what the original reason for introducing the `pow` definitions in this code were (especially since they are guarded by implementation macros), but in conformant standard C++ the definition

```
int pow(double a, int n) {
    return pow(a, (double)n);
}
```

in global namespace is going to cause trouble. Depending on the standard version, whether `<math.h>` and/or `<cmath>` are included directly or indirectly and dependent on the unspecified standard library implementation details, this may or may not be a valid definition.

The C++ standard library already offers an overload with signature `pow(double, int)` or potentially a template `pow` accepting these arguments and in the former case, the definition in user code will be an invalid redefinition if this overload/template is placed into the global namespace (including `math.h` always does that, including `<cmath>` may do that).

The second overload

```
int pow(int a, int n) {
    // versions for float/double are defined in stdlib.
    int r = a;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) r *= a;
    return r;
}
```

will cause similar issues, but only since C++11 (this overload did not exist before that and it has different semantics than the version here in C++11 and up).

Therefore this is simply a bug in the code. As workaround I noticed that (for some reason that is not clear to me) GCC versions 5.x and below do not seem to error on the definition, even though I tried to make sure that they would. Since 6.1 the overload always causes an error together with `#include<math.h>` and `-std=c++89`/`-std=gnu++89`.

You may also want to try compiling against `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`, because since C++11 implementations are allowed to implement the `pow` overloads as template functions, in which case no redefinition error would occur. (I think that was not allowed before C++11.) This seems to be the case with GCC in my testing.

Comment: It worked. by changing the -std=gnu++98 to -std=gnu++17.
Thank you very much
I know many who would appreciate your recommendation.