# Why can't the using keyword be used for a forward declaration when defining a function?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following header and source, in which a simple function `GiveMeATwo` is forward declared in the header `test.hpp`, within the namespace `SomeNamespace`, why does a conflict occur when trying to bring the function `GiveMeATwo` into scope via `using SomeNamespace::GiveMeATwo`, prior to defining `GiveMeATwo`?

test.hpp

```
#ifndef _TEST_HEADER_
#define _TEST_HEADER_

namespace SomeNamespace {
    int GiveMeATwo();
}

#endif
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp"

using SomeNamespace::GiveMeATwo;

int GiveMeATwo() {
    return 2;
}
```

Compiling with `Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)` yields the following error, indicating that the `using` statement somehow implicitly introduces a declaration?

```
test.cpp:5:5: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
int GiveMeATwo() {
    ^
./test.hpp:6:5: note: target of using declaration
int GiveMeATwo();
    ^
test.cpp:3:22: note: using declaration
using SomeNamespace::GiveMeATwo;
                     ^
1 error generated.
```

Furthermore, what is the difference between bringing the `GiveMeATwo` symbol into scope via `using namespace SomeNamespace`, versus `using SomeNamespace::GiveMeATwo` as I have done here?

Comment: Related: [error: ‘int pow(double, int)’ conflicts with a previous declaration int pow(double a, int n) {](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550148/error-int-powdouble-int-conflicts-with-a-previous-declaration-int-powdoub)

Comment: “indicating that the `using` statement somehow implicitly introduces a definition” — No, it indicates that the `using` statement is (explicitly!) introducing a *declaration*.

Comment: Quite right, a declaration. I'll amend the Q. However, that does lead me on to the question of the `using` statement introducing a declaration and why that conflicts with the definition of the function. How does this differ from a forward declaration of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives):

> If an entity is declared, but not defined in some inner namespace, and then declared through using-declaration in the outer namespace, and then a definition appears in the outer namespace with the same unqualified name, that definition is a member of the outer namespace and conflicts with the using-declaration

In other words, this definition:

```
int GiveMeATwo() {
    return 2;
}
```

is for *another* function. If you want to define the one in `SomeNamespace`, you still need to name the namespace, even if you wrote `using SomeNamespace::GiveMeATwo;` or `using namespace SomeNamespace;` before it:

```
int SomeNamespace::GiveMeATwo() {
    return 2;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dv451jqG6)

The using-directive (`using namespace`) is slightly different because:

> Using-directive does not add any names to the declarative region in which it appears (unlike the using-declaration), and thus does not prevent identical names from being declared.

So you can do this:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
    int GiveMeATwo();
}

using namespace SomeNamespace;

int GiveMeATwo() {
    return 2;
}
```

but it's somewhat useless because a call to `GiveMeATwo` is now ambiguous unless you qualify it, like `::GiveMeATwo();` for the outer function or `SomeNamespace::GiveMeATwo();` for the inner one.